# Why is https://www.foobar.com redirecting to itself?

Tags: nginx, redirect, 301-redirect

I don't have any rules that suggest `https://www.foobar.com` should redirect to `https://www.foobar.com`. But why is it doing that?

This is my `curl` output:

```
curl -Ik https://www.foobar.com
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Length: 184
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Wed, 11 Feb 2015 07:22:11 GMT
Location: https://www.foobar.com/
Server: nginx/1.4.7
Connection: keep-alive
```

Nginx config:

```
upstream unicorn_www.foobar.com {
 server unix:/srv/www/foobar/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name foobar.com;
  return 301 https://www.foobar.com$request_uri;
}
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.foobar.com;
  return 301 https://www.foobar.com$request_uri;
}
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name beta.foobar.com;
  return 301 https://www.foobar.com$request_uri;
}
server {
  listen 443;
  server_name foobar.com;
  return 301 https://www.foobar.com$request_uri;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/www.foobar.com.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/www.foobar.com.key;
}
server {
  listen 443;
  server_name beta.foobar.com;
  return 301 https://www.foobar.com$request_uri;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/www.foobar.com.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/www.foobar.com.key;
}

server {
  listen   443;
  server_name www.foobar.com foobar_staging pantherinae;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/www.foobar.com-ssl.access.log;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/www.foobar.com.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/www.foobar.com.key;

  keepalive_timeout 5;

  root /srv/www/foobar/current/public/;


  location / {
    try_files $uri/index.html $uri/index.htm @unicorn;
  }

  location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_read_timeout 60;
    proxy_send_timeout 60;

    # If you don't find the filename in the static files
    # Then request it from the unicorn server
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
      proxy_pass http://unicorn_www.foobar.com;
      break;
    }
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  location = /500.html {
    root /srv/www/foobar/current/public/;
  }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9448237/1016033

Comment: Are you using cloud flare?

Comment: @AD7six not cloud flate

Comment: Not that then, if in doubt you can use [add_header](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html) to determine which location block is in scope [like so](https://github.com/AD7six/server-configs-nginx/blob/location-debug/sites-available/nginx.dev#L46) (or, just enable the debug log and read what it's doing there).

Comment: For the server I want them to actually land at, I have `listen 443 default_server ssl;`

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

It is a redirect to add a trailing slash: from `www.example.com` to `www.example.com/`.
 From the [manual](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location)

> If a location is defined by a prefix string that ends with the slash
>   character, and requests are processed by one of proxy_pass,
>   fastcgi_pass, uwsgi_pass, scgi_pass, or memcached_pass, then the
>   special processing is performed. **In response to a request with URI
>   equal to this string, but without the trailing slash, a permanent
>   redirect with the code 301 will be returned to the requested URI with
>   the slash appended**.

I assume that the proxy_pass to unicorn is what triggers this.

You have a `location /` line in your config. You do a request with `curl -Ik https://www.foobar.com` (Note the missing trailing slash <kbd>/</kbd> in your request). Missing slash results in redirect to "correct" URL that matches the location directive `https://www.example.com/`.

Comment: Which line are you referring to in my code example?

Comment: @ChristianFazzini: updated my answer

Comment: I tried `curl -Ik https://www.foobar.com/` Same result

Comment: But do you get a repsonse body or is an infinite loop triggered?

Comment: Yeap, it still redirects back to itself